# How do I add a custom field for a new Okta app integration?

Tags: integration, saml, okta, okta-api

I am creating a new Okta integration for our app and need to require users to enter a subdomain, where can I do this? We will be using SAML.

As you can see in this example for the slack integration ( http://ronz.io/gPgAeS), they are able to add a custom field to allow for the domain or subdomain to be entered.

Where in the setup can I add this? So that Okta users can enter their subdomain for our app when adding the application.

Please let me know if you need any additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a custom application rather than an app in the OIN ? In which case you need to build a SAML templated app, which will allow you to add as many attributes required by the SP.

If you go to Applications -> Add Applications -> There should be a Create button on the page allowing you to define your app.